# 0 or n occurrences, but nothing else

Tags: python, regex

How would I do the following, to match either 2 or 0 digits?

```
[0-9]{0,2}
```

This is what I have so far, but this will match 0, 1, or 2 occurrences. I only want 0 or 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
([0-9]{2})?
```

Comment: With a disclaimer that, if you want it to validate strings with this as a full pattern (as opposed to simply finding substrings, or using it as a subpattern), you will need anchors (since any string will match 0 occurences of any pattern, and any string with 2+ occurences will match 2 occurences). EDIT: @Jongware read my mind :P (EDIT2: No disrespect meant, simply an addition, I already +1'd the answer)

Comment: @Amadan: Indeed, the same caveat would apply to the regex in the question, so I have assumed that such anchors, if necessary, were already included.

Answer (score 3):

Too easy (if you know how):

```
(\d\d)?
```

If this is in the context of an entire string, use

```
^(\d\d)?$
```

Inside another string, add boundaries:

```
(\b\d\d\b)?
```

Answer (score 2):

In the general case you could do

```
([0-9]{2}|[0-9]{0})  # place the {2} before {0} so that it tries that first.
```

In this particular case, since one of your matches is zero, take a look at @"Greg Hewgill"'s answer.